# How to use "correctAction" and "correctInstitutionTransactionId" in Intuit's Customer Account Data API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

My questions concern the  [Transaction](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0030_getaccounttransactions) data object in Intuit's Customer Account Data API.

I am not sure how to use the following fields (or even really what they mean):

1. correctAction:  The documentation does mention that "replace" and "delete" are possible values, which leads me to think that the word "correct" is being used to mean "fix", not as in the opposite of "incorrect".
2. correctInstitutionTransactionId:  The documentation does not provide any details on this field.  My best guess is that this id is used in conjunction with the "correctAction" field.  I do not know how.

How do I use these fields?